# iOS-App crashes when loading data with Just

Tags: swift, xcode, networking

I have an app that sometimes crashes. Not always, but every now and then it crashes. I think it has something to do with Just. I use this pod to do some network stuff. When I set an exception breakpoint, it jumps out at a function in the Just pod:

```
func makeTask(_ request: URLRequest, configuration: TaskConfiguration)
-> URLSessionDataTask? {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    taskConfigs[task.taskIdentifier] = configuration
    return task
}
```

The console shows the error message: "[_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000".

In the Crashlog it says:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x8000000000000008
VM Region Info: 0x8000000000000008 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 9223372025580486665  
  REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
  MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
  UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [28922]
Triggered by Thread:  4
```

Thread 4 looks like this:

```
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x283042520 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
 Thread 4 Crashed:
 0   libswiftCore.dylib
 1   Just
 2   Just
 3   Just
 4   Just
 5   Just
 6   Just
 7   [app name]
 8   [app name]
 9   [app name]
 10  Foundation
 11  Foundation
 12  Foundation
 13  Foundation
 14  libdispatch.dylib
 15  libdispatch.dylib
 16  libdispatch.dylib
 17  libdispatch.dylib
 18  libdispatch.dylib
 19  libdispatch.dylib
 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib
 21  libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

I have no clue why this happens. So I would appreciate some help from you guys.

Edit: This happens when I start the app on a newer iPhone, e.g iPhone 8 or iPhone X. When I run it on a 5s it doesn't crash. All devices have at least iOS 12.

Comment: try adding exception breakpoint. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/6783598

Comment: @BenRockey I did it, and it always stops in that makeTask-function from the Just pod. The console shows the error mentioned above (unrecognized selector).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it, if anyone is interested. The problem was that the new phones are too fast, and the app tried to read values that didn't exist already. So I added a small delay, and everything worked fine.